# Вопрос по созданию списка в kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

Как мне сделать список с такими элементами, как на картинке?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не понятно. Я думаю, что каждый такой item это отдельный виджет с Image, и с Label'ами. В pyqt5 я использовал для этого QListWidget и там просто добавляются итемы. Так что главный вопрос, как сделать такой список вот с такими элементами. Что вообще использовать? Буду благодарен за любую информацию) Версия kivy 1.10.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Библиотека KivyMD поможет. Сделайте запрос в Google, скачайте, посмотрите демо...